# Why is a "null reference" being reported when variable has a value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some C# code in my ASP.NET MVC3 project that's throwing an exception claiming:

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

The line of code throwing the exception is:

```
ViewBag.Foo[i].Name = allSpark[i].Users.Name;
```

This is the code block:

```
ViewBag.Foo = new myAllSparkModelType[allSpark.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < allSpark.Length; i++)
{
    ViewBag.Foo[i].Name = allSpark[i].Users.Name;
    ...
}
```

When I set a breakpoint and inspect `allSpark[i].Users.Name`, it definitely has a value (e.g. "Fred").

If I comment out this line of code, the next line (which is similar code) then throws the same exception.

So the problem is either that `allSpark[i].Users.Name` is a null reference (Which I've confirmed isn't) or I can't just use the `ViewBag` like I am. If it's the latter, I'm confused as I thought that the ViewBag could be used this way.

Comment: Can you provide some more code on the creation of the allSpark and ViewBag instance?

Comment: How about Foo[i] ? maybe it is null

Comment: Foo[i] must be null , to my understanding

Comment: Is Users a collection or just a variable?  Can you post your foreach code?

Comment: +1 for allspark. Autobots, roll out

Comment: Add watches on `ViewBag.Foo`, `ViewBag.Foo[i]` and `ViewBag.Foo[i].Name` and post what you've got.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
ViewBag.Foo = new myDataModelType[allSpark.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < allSpark.Length; i++)
{
    ViewBag.Foo[i].Name = ...
    ...
}
```

`ViewBag.Foo` is initialized, but each *element* of `ViewBag.Foo` will be `null`, assuming `myDataModelType` is a class. When you create an array, each element is initialized to the default value of the element type - and for reference types, that default value is null.

You need to create a new object for each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allSpark.Length; i++)
{
    ViewBag.Foo[i] = new myDataModelType();
    ViewBag.Foo[i].Name = ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Or, of course, `ViewBag.Foo[i] = new myDataModelType { Name = ..., Bar = ... };`. Or, if performing more complex operations on the item, `var item = new myDataModelType(); // operations on item; ViewBag.Foo[i] = item;` to save repeatedly indexing into the array.

Comment: @AdamRalph: Sure - I wanted to keep to minimal changes for the moment, but those are all good things to consider :)

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

If `allSpark[i].Users.Name` contains a value then it might be referencing the property on the left hand side.

Check to see if`ViewBag.Foo` exists, and then if it exists at position i.

Answer (score 1):

Either ViewBag is null and therefore .Foo[i] does not exist
or Foo is null and indexing it is not valid
or Foo[i] is null and therefore Foo[i].Name is not valid

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of ViewBag.Foo[i] before assigning Name to it.

```
ViewBag.Foo = new myDataModelType[allSpark.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < allSpark.Length; i++)
{

ViewBag.Foo[i] = new ObjectThatHasNameProperty();
    ViewBag.Foo[i].Name = allSpark[i].Users.Name;

}
```

`allSpark[i].Users.Name` has a value, but `ViewBag.Foo[i]` does not thus the exception.