# ASP.NET MVC consuming spotify web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spotify

I am trying to display an artist id on my view. I am able to display albums of an artist. I keeping getting an error that `ViewBag.Playlists.Items` is a null reference. I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any ideas would be helpful.

This is my home controller

```
namespace WebApplication7.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Search(string searching)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["token"].ToString()))
                return View("Index");

            var access_token = Session["token"].ToString();

            SpotifyService spotifyService = new SpotifyService();
            SpotifyUser spotifyUser = spotifyService.GetUserProfile(access_token);

            Playlists search = spotifyService.GetSearch("06HL4z0CvFAxyc27GXpf02", access_token);
            ViewBag.Search = search;

            return View();
            string Q = "what";

            ViewBag.Message = searching;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             ViewBag.AuthUri = GetAuthUri();
             return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AuthResponse(string access_token)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
                return View();
            else
            {
                 Session["token"] = access_token;
                 return RedirectToAction("ShowPlaylists");
            }
        }

        private string GetAuthUri()
        {
             string clientID = "86fa31dab3eb47bcb93f24b68f157706";
             string redirectUri = "http://localhost:64425/Home/AuthResponse";

             Scope scope = Scope.PLAYLIST_MODIFY_PRIVATE;

             return "https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?client_id=" + clientID +
                    "&response_type=token&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri +
                    "&state=&scope=" + scope.GetStringAttribute(" ") +
                    "&show_dialog=true";
        }

        public ActionResult ShowPlaylists()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["token"].ToString()))
                return View("Index");

            var access_token = Session["token"].ToString();

            SpotifyService spotifyService = new SpotifyService();
            SpotifyUser spotifyUser = spotifyService.GetUserProfile(access_token);

            Playlists playlists = spotifyService.GetPlaylists("06HL4z0CvFAxyc27GXpf02", access_token);

            ViewBag.Playlists = playlists;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I reference objects

```
public class Playlists
{
   [JsonProperty("items")]
   public List<Playlist> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Playlist
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public String Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public String Type { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("href")]
    public String Href { get; set; }

}
```

Spotify service controller

```
internal class SpotifyService
{
    public SpotifyService()
    {
    }

    public SpotifyUser GetUserProfile(string token)
    {
        string url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me";
        SpotifyUser spotifyUser = GetFromSpotify<SpotifyUser>(url, token);
        return spotifyUser;
    }

    public T GetFromSpotify<T>(string url, string token)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Set("Authorization", "Bearer" + " " + token);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

            T type = default(T);

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                    {
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        type = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseFromServer);
                    }
                }
            }
            return type;
        }
        catch (WebException )
        {
            return default(T);
        }
        catch (Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public Playlists GetPlaylists(string userId, string access_token)
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{0}/albums?market=ES", userId);
        Playlists playlists = GetFromSpotify<Playlists>(url, access_token);

        return playlists;
    }

    public Playlists GetSearch(string userId, string access_token)
    {
        string url = string.Format("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Bob&type=artist&limit=2&offset=20", userId);
        Playlists search = GetFromSpotify<Playlists>(url, access_token);

        return search;
    }
}
```

This displays my albums

```
       @if (ViewBag.Playlists != null) 
        {
            <h1>Playlist</h1>

            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Playlists.Items)
            {

                @item.Name

                <table style="width:50%;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> 
           <td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp; 
           </td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
           </table>

            }
        }
```

This is where i get my error when trying to display search id

```
              @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Playlists.Items)
                {

                @item.Id

             <table style="width:50%;"><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td> 
          <td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp; 
          </td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
         </table>

            }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a "null reference" being reported when variable has a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373708/why-is-a-null-reference-being-reported-when-variable-has-a-value)

Comment: Put breakpoint in your GET action method and check whether you are properly setting the `ViewBag.Playlists`value.

Comment: in search id which is the last section of code i am getting that Viewbag.Playlist.Items is a null reference.